# Retrieving the row with the greatest timestamp in questDB

Tags: questdb

I'm currently running QuestDB 6.1.2 on linux. How do I get the row with maximum value from a table? I have tried the following on a test table with around 5 million rows:

1. `select * from table where cast(timestamp as symbol) in (select cast(max(timestamp) as symbol) from table );`
2. `select * from table inner join (select max(timestamp) mm from table ) on timestamp >= mm`
3. `select * from table where timestamp = max(timestamp)`
4. `select * from table where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table )`

where 1 is correct but runs in ~5s, 2 is correct and runs in ~500ms but looks unnecessarily verbose for a query, 3 compiles but returns an empty table, and 4 is incorrect syntax although that's how sql usually does it

Answer (score 2):

`select * from table limit -1` works. QuestDB returns rows sorted by timestamp as default, and `limit -1` takes the last row, which happens to be the row with the greatest timestamp. To be explicit about ordering by timestamp, `select * from table order by timestamp limit -1` could be used instead. This query runs in around 300-400ms on the same table.

As a side note, the third query using `timestamp=max(timestamp)` doesn't work yet since QuestDB does not support subqueries in `where` yet (questDB 6.1.2).